# How to call a method in a select active record query interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to call a method in a select active record query interface from another method?

```
      # return quantity of boxes
  def amount_boxes(order_id)
    amount_boxes = OrderProduct.where('order_products.order_id' => order_id).where('order_products.box IS TRUE').pluck("SUM(order_products.quantity)").first

    if amount_boxes.nil? 
      0
    else
      amount_boxes
    end
  end

  # return amount boxes accumulated.
  def amount_boxes_accumulated(user_id, date_delivery)
    quantity = OrderHistory.joins(order: [:load, :order_products])
                          .select("DISTINCT order_histories.order_id, #{amount_boxes('order_histories.order_id')} as amount_boxes")
                          .where('loads.delivery_date' => date_delivery, 'order_histories.user_id' => user_id)
                          .where('order_products.box IS TRUE')
                          .where.not(end: nil)

    # time_total = OrderHistory.select("SUM(t.quantity) as amount_boxes").from(quantity, :t)

  end
```

In the amount_boxes_accumulated method I do the .. **# {amount_boxes ('order_histories.order_id')} as the amount_boxes** .. but this is not working.

What would be a viable way for this to work?

the result of what is there does not generate errors, only appears 0 in the query .. like ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_histories.order_id, 0 as amount_boxes FROM `order_histories` INNER JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`id` = `order_histories`.`order_id` INNER JOIN `loads` ON `loads`.`id` = `orders`.`load_id` INNER JOIN `order_products` ON `order_products`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` WHERE `loads`.`delivery_date` = '2019-09-25 00:00:00' AND `order_histories`.`user_id` = 931135 AND (order_products.box IS TRUE) AND `order_histories`.`end` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: When you say it is "not working", please specify errors, unexpected behavior, etc. "Not working" is not much to go on.

Comment: You must define _is not working_. You're passing or 0 or a whole object to the SELECT statement, what are you trying to do?

Comment: the result of what is there does not generate errors, only appears 0 in the query .. like ...

Comment: edit question. Thanks.

Comment: What about the result if you execute the `amount_boxes` query alone?

Comment: This result the amount_boxes is for example: 30, according to each order_id passed.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> .select("DISTINCT order_histories.order_id, #{amount_boxes('order_histories.order_id')} as amount_boxes")
>                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

This will not work like you hope. You can not call your ruby method from the database.

You can probably rewrite your query so that everything happens in the same DB request, but this is out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with:

```
def amount_boxes_accumulated(user_id, date_delivery, order_id)
quantity_boxes_for_order = amount_boxes(order_id)

quantity = OrderHistory.joins(order: [:load, :order_products])
                          .select("DISTINCT order_histories.order_id, #{quantity_boxes_for_order} as amount_boxes")
.....
```

Thanks.